# From pandas Dataframe to dataframe timeseries in 15minute Bins by sum rows

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID  Arrival_time
 ....
0   22  2019-01-01 05:34:10
1   23  2018-01-01 05:36:18
2   24  2018-01-01 05:44:24
3   25  2018-01-01 06:10:26
4   26  2018-01-01 06:08:28
5   27  2018-01-01 06:22:29 
 ....
```

I need a new dataframe which has a time series of 15min bins as index and a column with the counted ARRIVAL_TIME entries that are in this 15min.

For the above I expect something like:

```
                   COUNTED_ARRIVALS
....
2019-01-01 05:30     3
2019-01-01 05:45     0
2019-01-01 06:00     2
2019-01-01 06:15     1
2019-01-01 06:30     0
2019-01-01 06:45     0
2019-01-01 07:00     0
....
```

how can I implement this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for getting `15 minutes` round time and the use [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) with [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(df['Arrival_time'].dt.floor('15T'))['Arrival_time'].count()
        .resample('15T')
        .mean()
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
        .reset_index(name='Counted_Arrival'))

print(df)
         Arrival_time  Counted_Arrival
0 2019-01-01 05:30:00                3
1 2019-01-01 05:45:00                0
2 2019-01-01 06:00:00                2
3 2019-01-01 06:15:00                1
```

---

Dataframe original before transformation:

```
print(df)
   ID        Arrival_time
0  22 2019-01-01 05:34:10
1  23 2019-01-01 05:36:18
2  24 2019-01-01 05:44:24
3  25 2019-01-01 06:10:26
4  26 2019-01-01 06:08:28
5  27 2019-01-01 06:22:29
```

Comment: But there are some missings. I except 96 Intervalls per day. How can i include the 15min timebins where are 0 counted arrivals aswell?

Comment: @OrgosMos It is present in the solution. You can check for `2019-01-01 05:45:00` there are `0` counted arrivals.

Answer (score 1):

You can try of using `pd.cut` to get the bin of values which are there in time range

```
df

    1   time
0   21  2018-01-01 05:34:10
1   23  2018-01-01 05:36:18
2   24  2018-01-01 05:44:24
3   25  2018-01-01 06:10:26
4   26  2018-01-01 06:08:28
5   27  2018-01-01 06:22:29


bins = pd.date_range(start=df['time'].min().floor('15Min'),end=df['time'].max().floor('15Min'),freq='15Min')
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['time'],bins)).count()
```

Out:

```
                                           1    time
time        
(2018-01-01 05:30:00, 2018-01-01 05:45:00]  3   3
(2018-01-01 05:45:00, 2018-01-01 06:00:00]  0   0
(2018-01-01 06:00:00, 2018-01-01 06:15:00]  2   2
```